# Is there a way to send keystrokes to a specificed application in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keystroke

I am trying to write a script that sends text to the Zoom Meetings Application and the only way I have got it to work is to press 'alt-tab' to go to Zoom, copy text to clipboard, and then press enter. Observe:

```
import easygui, clipboard, time, pyautogui
    def alttab():
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
    clipboard.copy(text)
    alttab()
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v', 'enter')
```

However, this does not seem to be too reliable so is there a way to send keystrokes to a specific application such as Zoom?

Many thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you will need to use zoom APIs for this : https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/api-reference/zoom-api/chat-messages/sendachatmessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be dependent on your platform as the windows are managed by your OS.
I found a developing project which is only for windows right now. It's here, and is planned to be included in puautoGUi in future.

https://github.com/asweigart/PyGetWindow

If you read the readme, there is a way to get the zoom window, then activate it and then send keystroke.

Install from pip:

```sh
pip install pygetwindow
```

Place the title in zoom window in place of 'MyZoomTitle'

```py
zoomWindow = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('MyZoomTitle')[0]
if zoomWindow.isMinimized():
    zoomWindow.restore()
zoomWindow.activate()
```

This should work to activate the zoom window, then you can use other methods to send keystrokes.